# Data Validation and Security: From user input to browser output – PHP/MySQL/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, regex

I am trying to understand the steps I have to follow in order for data to be input and output securely on a website. This is what I understood so far:

**

### Procedure

**

1)User inputs data

2)This data is validated using **JavaScript**. If data doesn’t match the structure you 
requested, send an error message.

3)The data is also validated using **PHP** in case the JavaScript is disabled or not supported by the browser. The PHP validation will almost be identical to the JavaScript one. If data doesn’t match the requested structure, send an error message.

4)Open a **connection** with the database (PDO method)

5)Check input data against your database using **prepared statements** (PDO method) and return an error message if required [for example if the data is an email address then we cannot have 2 users with the same email address/ Error message: This email address is already registered. If you are already registered please login or use another email address to register].

6)After all checking is done [**client-side (JavaScript)** and **server-side (PHP)**], use prepared statements to insert **un-escaped** data into the database.

7)When data is requested and must be displayed on the web browser, **only then escape (output) data**, to prevent XSS.

**

### Security

**

A)The PHP script will use **session_regenerate_id** when there is a change in the level of privilege (from logged in to logged out and via versa) – **mitigate session fixation**

B)**SSL** will be used to minimize the exposure of data between the client and the server

C)The form will have a hidden field nesting an **anti-CSRF token**, that will be checked against the one stored in the session – **mitigate CSRF**

D)Passwords will be stored after hashing them with **Bcrypt hashing algorithm** (with a proper salt)

E)(2)+ (3) validation will use **Regular Expressions**. I understand that, a wrong Regular Expression can cause many errors. Are there any general accepted Regular Expressions for validating email address, passwords, etc?

**

### Questions:

**

1)Do I understand the input/output procedure correctly? Am I doing something wrong?

2)I know that security-wise you can never be 100% protected. What else should I do? Is something I write above wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow, sorry to say. You put a lot of thought into it.

Comment: I know that this is a huge part of PHP/MySQL/JavaScript. But i need to know whether i am in the correct path or not. Or if i am missing out something fundamental.

Comment: Email validation: __Don’t__ even start to try and write your own RegEx – this is __way__ to complex, and many people have failed at this before you already. Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Yes but this is for PHP only. What about JavaScript validation?

Comment: Password validation: Don’t you effin’ __dare__ to tell me what my password should look like ;-) Seriously, _forcing_ users to use passwords that conform to what _you_ might think is a correct form/number of “special” characters makes the world _less_ secure – it forces me to deviate from my usual scheme, and thereby increases the likeliness that I will chose something “easy to remember”, or write it down somewhere, etc. You might _advise_ me that you think my password might be not the most secure one – but please don’t _force_ anything on me in that regard.

Comment: _“What about JavaScript validation?”_ – HTML5 `input type=email` – if my browser supports it, fine – if not, well then the server-side validation will have to alert me to the fact that my entered email address is not syntactically valid.

Comment: I agree on what you say about password validation. The validation might ask for password length to be longer that 5 chars or something.

Comment: @CBroe: What if i have a drop down selection with the values a,b,c? As i understand a drop down value is added by the developer of the script, so is there a need to validate it?I have read that "Just because a field contains a certain values, dont think that you can't get back something totally different, such as a PHP code,SQL,etc".

Comment: Of course you need to validate it … when you even think for a moment, that any request that reaches your server has to come from something called a “browser”, that would be wrong already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you understand it all right in general.
2. That's, as you noted yourself, is an endlessly open topic. There are thousands vectors. Some of them are `include injection` (never include or read a file taken blindly from user input), `eval` (avoid this operator as a hot iron), `upload injection` is alone a wide topic with multiple issues (in short, always verify input data format)

As of regexps - oh, yes. Just try google.

Comment: I have been reading for a long time to clear these things out, and i am sure that i have barely scratched the surface. But thanks for the answer.Being in the correct path, its a good start. Now its time to go deeper into the details.